# Merge multiple excel files, while keeping the Header Row from first File only

Tags: vba, excel

I tried searching for this a lot, but could not find a satisfactory answer. Sorry if it's a repost.

What I basically want is to merge multiple excel files into one workbook. I only want to keep the header row from the first excel file and ignore header row of the remaining excel files (as they are all the same). So the end result should be the Header + data from the first excel file and from the remaining excel file I only need the data rows, not the first row which has column heading similar to the first file. 
The below copy paste all the rows and columns from all the excel files. Thank you for helping me.

```
For wbCounter = 1 To UBound(books)

                Set wbSource = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(books(wbCounter))
                For wsCounter = 1 To wbSource.Sheets.Count
                    Set wsSource = wbSource.Sheets(wsCounter)

                    If wsSource.Name Like selectSheetStr Then
                        emptySheet = True

                        If cbOptionIgnoreEmpty.Value = True And wsSource.UsedRange.Address = "$A$1" Then
                            emptySheet = True
                        Else
                            emptySheet = False
                        End If

                        If emptySheet = False Then
                            mergedWorksheetName = wsSource.Name

                            sheetExist = SheetExists(mergedWorksheetName, wbResult)
                            If (cbOptionAppendData.Value = True And sheetExist = True) Then
                                Set wsMergeResult = wbResult.Sheets(mergedWorksheetName)
                                wsSource.UsedRange.Copy
                                wsMergeResult.Cells(wsMergeResult.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1, 1).Resize(wsSource.UsedRange.Rows.Count, wsSource.UsedRange.Columns.Count).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone
                                mergedWorksheetCount = mergedWorksheetCount + 1
                                'Name of Worksheet
                                wsResult.Cells(mergedWorksheetCount + 1, 1) = wsMergeResult.Name
                                'Fullpath of Workbook
                                wsResult.Cells(mergedWorksheetCount + 1, 2) = wbSource.FullName
                            Else
                                wsSource.Copy After:=wbResult.Sheets(wbResult.Sheets.Count)
                                mergedWorksheetCount = mergedWorksheetCount + 1
                                wsResult.Cells(mergedWorksheetCount + 1, 1) = .ActiveSheet.Name
                                wsResult.Cells(mergedWorksheetCount + 1, 2) = wbSource.FullName
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
                Next wsCounter
                wbSource.Close SaveChanges:=False
            Next wbCounter
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing the line...

```
wsSource.UsedRange.Copy
```

...with:

```
wsSource.UsedRange.Resize(wsSource.UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1, wsSource.UsedRange.Columns.Count).Offset(1, 0).Copy
```

This should copy the used range minus the frist row.

Comment: Thanks Soren. It does remove the column names from the remaining excel  files. Just one more thing to ask hope you won't mind, incase I have 1 row record in my remaining excel files, it is copy pasting the rows twice. So a record in second excel sheet (with one row record only) is being copied twice on the master excel file (I mean the final merged excel workbook). Do you have any idea why it could be? Thank you for your help again.

Comment: I am affraid that I don't excatly understand your second question. Perhaps it would be better to describe this in a new question? Pleace accept the answer if it worked for you.

Comment: Thanks Soren. I will add a new question.

Answer (score -1):

This code will get you the path of all the files in a specific folder

```
Option Explicit
Sub CountRows()

    Dim MyObject As Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Set MyObject = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Dim mySource As Folder
    Dim myFile As Scripting.File

    Dim strPath As String

    Set mySource = MyObject.GetFolder("D:\") ' or any other folder
    For Each myFile In mySource.Files
        strPath = myFile.Path
   Next
End Sub
```

this code will open those workbooks and modify their cells

```
dim wrkbook as workbook
set wrkbook = workbooks.open(strPath) ' the path comes from the code above
'modify the workbook
wrkbook.worksheets.item(1).cells(1, 1) = "something"
```